# Issue importing cordova project to Eclipse (ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, adt

I'm trying to import a android cordova project to Eclipse:

I run the followings commands in CMD:

```
cordova create XYZ com.falk.xyz XINF
cordova platform add android
cordova build
```

Then I imported the XYZ\platforms\android folder to Eclipse

[image]

```
CONSOLE:
/XINF/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
```

Also, I do this:

> Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix
>   Project Properties" Project -> Clean

Please, someone can help me?

Comment: You should NOT import. Create Android application from existing sources. Point to the android subdirectory of your project

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Right click on the project and go to "Properties"
Select "Java Build Path" on the left
Open "Source" tab
Click "Add Folder..."
Check "gen" folder and click Ok and Ok again
Again right click on the project and in the "Andriod Tools" click on "Fix Project Properties"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the command line  interface
 use the following codes :

```
cordova create XYZ com.falk.xyz XINF


cd XYZ

cordova platform  add android 


cordova build
```

use this command line  or you can use the phone gap command too

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way how the project was "INCLUDED" into Eclipse. NEWER use import. Create Android application from existing sources. Point to the android subdirectory of your project. Now it works.